# Highlight specific words in a sentence in python

Tags: python, termcolor

I have some text, and I want to highlight specific words.
I wrote a script to loop through the words and highlight the desired text, but how do I set this up to return it to sentences?

```
from termcolor import colored

text = 'left foot right foot left foot right. Feet in the day, feet at night.'
l1 = ['foot', 'feet']
for t in text.lower().split():
    if t in l1:
        print(colored(t, 'white', 'on_red'))
    else: print(t)
```

In the above example, I want to end up with an output of two sentences, not a list of all the words, with relevant words highlighted

Answer (score 6):

Use `str.join`

**Ex:**

```
from termcolor import colored
text='left foot right foot left foot right. Feet in the day, feet at night.'
l1=['foot','feet']
result = " ".join(colored(t,'white','on_red') if t in l1 else t for t in text.lower().split())
print(result)
```

Comment: Hi @Rakesh - can you guide on how this exact result can be achieved for a phrase in it's entirety without having to chop the words separately?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to have the entire words in a list and join then with space

```
from termcolor import colored
text='left foot right foot left foot right. Feet in the day, feet at night.'
l1=['foot','feet']
formattedText = []
for t in text.lower().split():
    if t in l1:
        formattedText.append(colored(t,'white','on_red'))
    else: 
        formattedText.append(t)

print(" ".join(formattedText))
```

Result below :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `end=" "` inside print() to make everything a sentence.

Example:

```
from termcolor import colored
text='left foot right foot left foot right. Feet in the day, feet at night.'
l1=['foot','feet']
for t in text.lower().split():
    if t in l1:
        print(colored(t,'white','on_red'), end=" ")
    else: print(t, end=" ")
print("\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you could split your sentence before loop, and try instruction as below.

```
ic = text.lower().split()
for ix, el in enumerate(ic):
    if el in list_of_words:
        # Run your instructions
        ic[ix] = colored(el,'white','on_red'), end=" "
```

Second sentence will be then:

```
output = ' '.join(ic)
```

Answer (score 0):

to have a better speed than @Rakesh suggested solution I will recommend to use:

```
from functools import reduce
from itertools import chain

text = 'left foot right foot left foot right. Feet in the day, feet at night.'
l1 = ['foot','feet']

print(reduce(lambda t, x: t.replace(*x), chain([text.lower()], ((t, colored(t,'white','on_red')) for t in l1))))
```

[image]

And the performances: 
[image]